# how to delete room database when app closed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i tried to call ViewModel to delete table when activity Destroy but it not work, when i call ViewModel when activity stop i get a error.

DAO interface

```
@Dao
interface NoteDAO {

    @Query("select * from note_table")
    fun getAllNote() : LiveData<List<Note>>

        @Query("DELETE FROM note_table")
        fun deleteAllData()
}
```

Repository

```
class NoteRepository(app:Application) {
    private val noteDAO : NoteDAO
    init {
        val noteDatabase: NoteDatabase = NoteDatabase.getInstance(app)
        noteDAO = noteDatabase.getNoteDao()
    }

    fun getAllNote():LiveData<List<Note>> = noteDAO.getAllNote()

    fun deleteAllData() = noteDAO.deleteAllData()
}
```

Viewmodel

```
class NoteViewModel(app: Application): ViewModel() {
    private val noteRepository: NoteRepository = NoteRepository(app)
    
    fun deleteAllData() = noteRepository.deleteAllData()

    fun getAllNote() : LiveData<List<Note>> = noteRepository.getAllNote()

    class NoteViewModelFactory(private val application: Application) : ViewModelProvider.Factory{
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if(modelClass.isAssignableFrom(NoteViewModel::class.java)){
                return NoteViewModel(application) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable construct viewmodel")
        }
    }
}
```

when i call in onStop method

```
 override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        noteViewModel.deleteAllData()
    }
```

i get the error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4624)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4594)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4669)
        at android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem.execute(StopActivityItem.java:41)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**please help me and have a nice day,everyone!**

Comment: Cannot access database on the main thread...

Comment: First change `@Query("DELETE FROM note_table")` to `@Query("DELETE * FROM note_table")`. Second, you cannot do DB operations on the main thread you can tackle that with `.allowMainThreadQueries()` when you are building your DB.

Comment: Use a background thread to access the database.

Comment: Thank you so much but i think use coroutines may be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
deleteDatabase(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);
```

Or

```
new Thread(() -> AppDatabase.getInstance(NavigationActivity.this).clearAllTables()).start();    //clear all rows from database
```

Comment: I'll try. Thank anyone so much much!

Comment: it work perfertly. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

if you want to perform database operation on main thread then add this line while building database object

```
.allowMainThreadQueries()
```

Full Sample

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext,LocalDatabase::class.java,"app.db")
     .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
     .allowMainThreadQueries()
     .build()
```

But It's not good practice to perform a database operation on the main thread.
You must use coroutines to perform database operation

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the onStop lifecycle function, calling the viewmodel, and in the viewmodel calling a coroutine executed in a background thread.

Activity/Fragment:

```
 override fun onStop() {
      viewModel.wipeData()
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel @Inject constructor (wipeDataUseCase: WipeDataUseCase){
    fun wipeData() {
    
       viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
           when (wipeDataUseCase()){
               true -> {
                  //do something
               }
               false -> {
                  // do something
               }

           }
       }
    }
}
```

Use Case:

```
class WipeDataUseCase @Inject constructor (roomDataBase: RoomDataBase){
  suspend operator fun invoke() = roomDataBase.dao().wipeData()
}
```

I would've use the coroutine mentioned above, launching the process in the background calling its respective Use Case.

As it is meant to be on the moment that the app is over there is no much thing to play with the callback of the wiping data operation.

Comment: To delete your database, you can use deleteDatabase(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME); or you can clear all tables using  new Thread(() -> AppDatabase.getInstance(NavigationActivity.this).clearAllTables()).start();    //clear all rows from database

Comment: I'll try. Thank you so much and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

To delete your database, you can use

```
deleteDatabase(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);
```

or

```
  new Thread(() -> AppDatabase.getInstance(NavigationActivity.this).clearAllTables()).start();
```

//clear all rows from database

Comment: I'll try. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

You are running a database query on `Main Thread` which could potentially block UI. You should use coroutines to execute your queries on the background thread.

Make your `deleteAllData` method `suspend`

```
@Query("DELETE FROM note_table")
suspend fun deleteAllData()
```

Also, make `deleteAllData` method `suspend` in `NoteRespository`

```
suspend fun deleteAllData() = noteDAO.deleteAllData()
```

In your `NoteViewModel` class, call this method in `viewModelScope`

```
fun deleteAllData() = viewModelScope.launch {
        noteRepository.deleteAllData()
    }
```

Comment: i tried but it not work, however thank you so much and have a nice day, bro!